# Can I use Unprocessable entity and a response?

Tags: http

I have the following case. The user need to be able to upload a spreadsheet (csv) but if there are errors (for example a value supposed to be a Integer is not a number) I need to display the full csv as a table with a red background on the invalid cell.
What status should I use, 422 or 200 ? In a way, I can process the entity, and can do something with it (displaying it with errors in red) but not go further.

Comment: To me, it's a client error and a 422 response code seems like a good fit. A [standards document](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4918#section-11.2) for 422 states its use when the request entity is "semantically erroneous"; which I think matches your situation. 200 seems wrong as it isn't fully successful.

Comment: I agree with Sam. Note that a normal user won't see any difference (unless they open the debugging-tool in their browser) but returning a 422 will definitely help if you're going to use your tool (now or in future) for automatic processing CSV's.